# C#/Why does Get html returns random junk characters?

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient, downloadstring

I have this for ex:
[Link](http://demonscity.combats.com/zayavka.pl?logs=08_07_11&filter=Alex)

This code:

```
const String nick = "Alex";
const String log = "http://demonscity.combats.com/zayavka.pl?logs=";
foreach (DateTime cd in dateRange)
{
string str = log + String.Format("{0:MM_dd_yy}", cd.Date) + "&filter=" + nick;
String htmlCode = wc.DownloadString(str);
}
```

returns something...."‹\b\0\0\0\0\0\0я•XYsЫЦ~зЇёѕ™d)bг.тBҐ$ЪRЖ’<2УN&сh@р ’„\f\0J–—_Фџђ§¤нt¦г6ќѕУЄђ0’IQtТґcµо№X(jі-Щ/Ђі|g?`yҐ¶ц"

Other links works fine.
I think the problem is with codepage, how can i fix it? Or it's server problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the response is GZip-compressed (response has a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header). You need to first decompress it, then you'll be able to read it:

```
public class StackOverflow_6660689
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
        byte[] data = wc.DownloadData("http://demonscity.combats.com/zayavka.pl?logs=08_07_11&filter=Alex");
        GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(data), CompressionMode.Decompress);
        MemoryStream decompressed = new MemoryStream();
        gzip.CopyTo(decompressed);
        string str = encoding.GetString(decompressed.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)decompressed.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is returning result in gzip format which it should not unless client explicitly accepts the format.